# Tell PHP backend that browser has closed from frontend Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I have an Angular project that communicates with a backend project made with PHP and ZF3.

I would like to know what's the best way to tell the backend project that the browser was closed?

I had thought of sending an http request when the event beforeunload is fired but the request is canceled even if I use async/await.

The other way I thought is using websocket connection, but it seems very complex to implement in PHP just to know when the user left the browser.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Rather open ended question.  If you don't like websockets, you could always go the long polling route.  Have the client ping the server every so often to let it know it's still alive.  If the threshold of the keep alive pings expires, the server knows the client left.

Comment: how can I accomplish that ?

Comment: Simple usage or `setInterval` or a recursive `setTimeout` to make the ajax calls would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to use the [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method:

Simple example:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
  navigator.sendBeacon('url/to/backend');
});
```

Because you use angular, you can place this on your `AppComponent` (although it might not be the right place)

```
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload')
  onUnload = () => navigator.sendBeacon('url/to/backend');
}
```

Comment: It is not compatible with internet explorer.

Comment: @shiqo if you google 'sendbeacon polyfill' you'll find plenty of examples :)